# What are the different types of Storage for a document in amazon s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

My specific requirement is I want to change storage type of document to 'ARCHIVED' is there any provision for this one.

Comment: Right-click on file -> Change Storage Class -> One Zone-IA for lower price for this item.

Comment: What is your definition of "Archived"? There is no such type in Amazon S3.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein, I got the solution I can do it by using the se Metadata map.

Comment: Thanks @Justinas, I wanted to do it through java, I did it using the s3 metadata map.